# Sum of the infinite series with square roots

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following infinite series:

$\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{1-x/2}{2}} + \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{(1-x/2)(1-x/3)}{3}} + \frac{1}{5}\sqrt{\frac{(1-x/2)(1-x/3) (1-x/4)}{4}} + \ldots \qquad$, where, $ -1 < x < 1$.

I checked it numerically that this series converges. However, I was wondering if there is a general formula for finding the sum of this infinite series.
I tried telescoping, partial fractions, etc. but in vain.
Any thoughts/ideas related to this problem are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form for even $x=0.$ There is not closed formula for $\sum \frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}},$ which is similar.

Comment: The compact form for this sum is, $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\sqrt{\binom{n-x}{n-1}}$$

Comment: @saulspatz: I get the ratio test to inconclusive because the $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{n(n-1)(n-x)}{(n+1)^2n}} $$ which is one. Can you please share your calculations.

Comment: I said the ratio test in a previous comment, when I meant the root test, but writing it out, it doesn't appear that the root test works either.  I'll have to think about it when I'm thinking more clearly than I am now.  Sorry.